# Mapping two lists together

Tags: python

I have this line

```
state_names = ["Alaska", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "American Samoa", "Arizona", "California", "Colorado",
               "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii",
               "Iowa", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Massachusetts",
               "Maryland", "Maine", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Missouri", "Mississippi", "Montana", "North Carolina",
               "North Dakota", "Nebraska", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "Nevada", "New York",
               "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina",
               "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Virginia", "Vermont", "Washington",
               "Wisconsin", "West Virginia", "Wyoming"]
```

and i have the prices

```
state_price = [22.75,14.24,11.75,14.77,13.13,25.15,13.83,27.10,13.40,13.69,13.46,41.57,12.09,9.86,15.06,14.70,14.11,12.63,11.98,24.25,14.16,25.36,17.65,13.84,11.54,13.14,11.00,12.26,10.48,11.11,23.16,17.04,13.74,13.89,21.05,13.18,12.38,11.22,14.93,20.26,14.00,12.03,11.94,13.08,10.66,12.84,20.23,10.12,15.37,13.24,11.06]
```

i want to map each state to each price so that i can have an output to print like "The price in alaska is 22.75". So far i was able to do the state to work but cant map the prices to each of them.
here is my code

```
user_state=input("What state are you in?: ").title()
```

print('The current rate in',user_state,'is',kwh,)

Comment: Is there a reason you have these as separate lists and not just a `dict` of `state name->price`?

Comment: If you want to map *each* state, what's the point of the `input`?

Comment: so originally, i was working on each state then using the internet to put in the prices but now, i want to map them to each other, so that's why i have input

Comment: Convert it to `dict` or from `state_names` find the index and print `state_price` with the index. Best is to go with `dict`. To get `dict` you can use **dict comprehension** `{name:price for name,price in zip(state_names,state_price)}` and use this dict.

Comment: @wkl yes, the reason was because i was trying to see if i could either map them or create an Xls file for them but now, ill try your way and let you know

Comment: `dict(zip(l1, l2))`

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the two lists into a dictionary. I did the first key-value pair to demonstrate:

```
state_choice = input().title()
state_names = {"Alaska": "22.75"}

print(f"The current rate in {state_choice} is {state_names.get(state_choice)}kwh.")
```

Comment: so i have to manually map each price to state. phew, alright. ill let you know with an update

Comment: seen it. will work on it and post an update

Comment: @j1-lee update, the code worked and my result came out as expected. Thanks for the help(i know i am not supposed to say it but)

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to have a dict, instead of the two lists; you can use `zip` for that. And then you can use that dict to get information easily.

```py
# convert into a dict
prices = dict(zip(state_names, state_price))

state = "New York"
# or, to get user input:
# state = input("Which state are you interested in? ")

print(f"The current rate in {state} is {prices[state]} kWh.")
# The current rate in New York is 21.05 kWh.
```

Comment: update, the code worked and my result came out as expected. Thanks for the help(i know i am not supposed to say it but)